# React router not loading script from public/index.html

Tags: reactjs, react-router

in public/index.html I have added:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="app-env.js"></script>
```

which is doing adding to window object host variables:

```
window.APP_ENV = {
    REACT_APP_BACKEND_URL : REACT_APP_BACKEND_URL,
...
```

I am doing it this way, because its easier to make 1 build folder once and later while deploying just change url there ( via `sed` or smth similar ).
It works fine when I will go to main page, but if I will go directly to the page under router path its not loaded..
How can I achieve this goal ? thanks

Answer (score 0):

Ah I just found solution:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/app-env.js"></script>
```

I needed to add `/` before app-env.js.

Answer (score 0):

You have to put the host url or add slash before the src value if you're in the same host.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="[host url]/app-env.js"></script>
```

I hope this helps you.